# htaccess subdomai page redirection to root page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I can't do the right rediect. I need to redirect:

> subdomain.example.com/specific-page

**to**

> example.com/specific-page

I did the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com/specific-page/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/specific-page/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Apparently, it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^specific-page/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/specific-page/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it doesn't seem working fine for me; I did the following: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^campaigns\.guardrfid\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^rfidjounrallive2018/(.*)$ https://www.guardrfid.com/real-time-asset-tracking/$1 [L,NC,R=302]